# problem adding object to hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am trying to call a class method dynamically depending on a condition. This is how I am doing it

I have three classes implement a single interface

```
interface IReadFile
{
    string DoStuff();
}
```

The three classes A,B,C implement the interface above.

I am trying to add them to a hashtable with the code below

```
        _HashT.Add("a", new classA());
        _HashT.Add("b", new classB());
        _HashT.Add("c", new classC());
```

This compiles fine, but gives a runtime error.**{Object reference not set to an instance of an object.}**

I was planning to return the correct class to the interface type depending on a parameter that matches the key value. say if I send in a. ClassA is returned to the interface type and the method is called.

```
        IReadFile Obj = (IReadFile )_HashT["a"].GetType();
        obj.DoStuff();
```

How do I correct the part above where the objects need to be added to the hashtable? Or do I need to use a different approach? All the classes are in the same assembly and namespace.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a guess, you have not instantiated your `_HashT` object.

You need somewhere in your code (declaration or constructor probably) to instantiate it:

```
HashTable _HashT = new HashTable();
```

If you do not do this, `_HashT` will be `null` and an attempt to `add` to it will fail with a `NullReferenceException` as you have been getting.

Comment: thanks :) I tend to forget things like this when I get back to coding after like an 8 month long break!

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are seeing a `NullReferenceException`. Based on the limited code you provided I would say it is likely that the `_HashT` variable is not assigned. It could be possible that the exception is being generated from one of your class constructors as well.

If you use `Dictionary<>` you can use the following code to add and extract objects from the hashtable.

```
var hashtable = new Dictionary<IReadFile>();
hashtable.Add("a", new ClassA());
hashtable.Add("b", new ClassB());
hashtable.Add("c", new ClassC());
IReadFile obj = hashtable["a"];
obj.DoStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach, you do not need to call `GetType()` on the value you pull out of `_HashT`. The value should already be an object of type `IReadFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `GetType`? The `IReadFile` object is the thing you are putting in the hash. Casting a `Type` object into a `IReadFile` is not going to cast correctly.